# Aye - Bye - Gye -?

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, acrostic

I've got a new puzzle for everyone; as always I hope you enjoy, and best of luck!

---

> I'm not sure where the best place to start this story is, so I suppose I'll start with tomorrow.
>
> You see, yesterday was riddled with lectures about Plato and his views on politics.
>
> I'm not sure how much longer I can stand it, I mean, I'd wager that Socrates could go on and on for millennia without breathing.
>
> Learning this language is proving to be a nightmare, and is sure to scar me for the rest of my life if I have to listen to one more trial.
>
> Can someone please help me?

Explain the title.

Comment: So many puzzles!

Comment: @Duck I’ve been away for a while and have been building them up. I’ve got about five more but I want to make sure those are 100% ready to go since I’m a bit more attached to them lol

Comment: Iyimlic? Acrostic tag...

Comment: well, I got the title and perhaps the 4th para in the block quote, but the others has made no sense to my crippled brain...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partial answer to "Explain the title": **Aye - Bye - Gye - ?**

> Plato and Socrates are mentioned. They were Greeks.
>  The title uses the first three letters of the Greek alphabet : Alpha, Beta, Gamma.
>  So Delta could be the basis for the next:
>
>  **Aye - Bye - Gye - Dye**
>
>  Obviously this can't be the full answer because it takes no account of the question tags.

Comment: Oh, but it does. If you Stack each “word” from the title in a column and take the first letter you get an acrostic. The mentions you speak of are hints to use your knowledge about Greece, and lateral thinking would be involved to realize the acrostic is actually in the title. :D Well done!

Comment: Oh oh! Surprise!